# Is there any good way to demonstrate Debye plasma shielding in a classroom?

Tags: education, plasma-physics, debye-length

In this age of amazing information exchange, despite loads of glorious YouTube DIY science channels, I haven't seen anyone demonstrate Debye plasma shielding. I can imagine it might be hard to come up with a satisfying demonstration (after all we can't even directly see the shielding electron cloud), but I'm curious if there is one out there. Bonus points if it could be done in a reasonably equipped classroom with modest physics equipment (vacuum chambers, cathode ray tubes, etc.).

Comment: This may be difficult as the typical Debye length for any lab-made plasma tends to be on the micron-or-smaller scale.  It may be easier to show a consequence of Debye shielding than the effect itself, e.g., some form of collective behavior.